# Install FreeIPA 4.1.0 on CentOS 6

Tags: centos, centos6, centos7, freeipa

I have installed FreeIPA master server in version 4.1.0 on the server with CentOS 7.1 and I need install replication server on the machine with Centos 6.

Is there a way, how to install ipa-server package (version 4.1.0) on CentOS 6.3(64-bit) or CentOS 6.4(32-bit)?? Centos 6 has in repositories just ipa-server in version 3.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways but almost all of them are painfull. One way you can do is to download the source files of IPA and self-compile on your CentOS 6.

But be aware that IPA has lots of dependencies as I do work myself on IPA as well. therefore, you will need to download manually all dependencies.

Alternatively, give it a try by downloading the entire suite of IPA 4 with all dependencies rpms and install using rpms, never tried so not sure if it works.

good luck.